# Optimizing website for desktop version and mobile versions

Tags: wordpress, optimization, vs-web-site-project

I'm trying to speed up my website built in using Wordpress.
Caching is enabled for most parts of the site, also I'm using cloudflare to speed it up.

When I ran couple of tests, to check optimization and speed of my site, I had some issues showing up in css sections and some font headers, that took a lot of time to load. Theme that I used for wordpress site was ASTRA theme. However, I am having problems now finding those in my main database, to make corrections.

Domain and hostings are from HOSTGATOR, hatchling plan.
Website page is : [healthy-paradise.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO4hf.png)

I'm still building up this site.

Anyone to try to help me out and tell, where can I locate these files, folders and directories, to make changes, and what needs to be changes?
Link of picture attached shows files in question..

Best regards to everyone.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tc53zz

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see what you can ask here and the best way to ask it so you get the help you need. For questions that are not coding related, try asking on the relevant site from the list of [other StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to understand a few thing about website performances. There is no "perfect" website, getting the 100% on google page speed insight or lighthouse is nearly impossible, but you can get close.
Most of the theme available (free or for purchase) are using what we call "libraries" or "framework" made to ease the development process. The downside of those website is that you're loading more content, tools, code than necessary.

For example your website is using jquery (an heavy js library) and bootstrap (css framework). So you're already losing performances on that end. Usually you can't do anything for that beside properly loading scripts (loading them from the function.php file ... etc).

From what I can see you're losing a lot of performances on your image sizing, this you can control, your images should be optimized for web with proper format, size and dimensions.

One other big thing is that you're not using ssl. which also impact performances.

Anyway I think you should get it now, fix all you can fix, and you should be good.
https://web.dev/measure/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw9IX4BRCcARIsAOD2OB2k4TK53FGVyn-B2ASY_46zmbyHBzUAmI_Cj6UWvHBi9_3jiKbeAKAaAiqTEALw_wcB